Prove that two sets are disjoint
The problem
I need to compare to sets of elements to tell if they are disjoint.
The sets are described with a boolean expression. A boolean expression consists of predicates joined with AND or OR conditions. A simplest boolean expression is a predicate of form $X(x) = V$, where X is a property of an element x and V is the value of that property.
Examples
For example, let's say there is a set of elements that have properties: X, Y and Z. Lets write the value of the property X of an element x like this: $X(x)$. The properties X and Y can only be describe with predicates of form: $X(x) = V$. The property Z of an element x can be describe with the following predicates: $Z(x) = V$ or $Z(x) \gt V$.
Example 1
Subset $A = \{x | X(x) = V\}$
Subset $B = \{x | X(x) = W\}$
The subsets A and B are disjoint with regards to the boolean expressions they are defined by.
Example 2
$A = \{x|X(x) = V \cap Z(x) \gt W\}$
$B = \{x |Z(x) \gt W \}$
In this case $A \subset B$.
Example 3
Subset $A = \{x | X(x) = V \cup (X(x) = U \cap Z(x) \lt W) \}$
Subset $B = \{x | Z(x) \gt V \cap Z(x) \lt W\}$, given $V \lt W$
In this case $B \subset A$.
The question
I would like to know if there is a general solution to this problem.
Any suggestion to the references where I can read about the problem or solution are highly appreciated.
Thank you!

If $A={x \mid \phi (x)}$ and $B={x\mid \gamma (x)}$ then the condition on $\phi$ and $\gamma$ is: not$(\phi \mbox{ and } \gamma)$.

Hey, @Malady! Thank you for your comment. If I understand it correctly, we assume that the $A \cup B$ and now we see if this set is empty. From what I can tell it is a working approach, but now the problem is how to prove that a set is empty.
